# Extracting characters only in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have the following sample data in a SQL Server 2014 database

- xxxx,yyyy: 679459
- xxxx,yyyy:679459
- xxxx,yyyy : 679459
- xxxx,yyyy :679459

As you can see there is no uniformity of the way the data is written and is written in any of the above formats.

I'm trying to only extract the last and first names i.e. xxxx,yyyy

From some internet searches I found the following and tried it

`left(EMP_CLass_9_descr, isnull(nullif(charindex(' :', EMP_CLass_9_descr),0) - 1,8000)) As TM_NAME`

This only worked where there is a space before the :

I also tried

```
left(EMP_CLass_9_descr, isnull(nullif(charindex(':', EMP_CLass_9_descr),0) - 1,8000)) As TM_NAME
```

and that then includes a space in the scenario where it's written as

- xxxx,yyyy :679459

Is there is way that this can be written where I only extract the xxxx,yyyy?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: Your current query does that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasmac,
You were almost there. Try this:

```
left(EMP_CLass_9_descr, isnull(nullif(charindex(':', REPLACE(EMP_CLass_9_descr,' ','')),0) - 1,8000)) As TM_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks a million John.  That works!!  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(left(EMP_CLass_9_descr,
                        charindex(':', EMP_CLass_9_descr + ':'
                                 )
                        )
                  ))
```

This looks for the `':'`, but also makes sure that there is one by appending a colon to the end of the name.  It then trims the returned value to get rid of leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you solution did exactly what you said but the solution provided by John was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks and much appreciated

Comment: @rasmac . . . I think this version is simpler.